# Analizar respuesta de servidor

Tags: python, socket

Dentro de un proyecto que estoy haciendo tengo que establecer una conexión por socket con un servidor que me responde con un código de error o acierto cada vez.
El código de acierto es `RPRT 0`. Quisiera que mi programa cuando reciba eso imprima en pantalla envío correcto y que en los demás casos se lo hiciese saber al usuario.
Lo he intentado con un bucle `if` pero creo que no he establecido bien la condición porque no lo consigo.
Este es mi código:

```
# message sent to server
            s.send(message.encode(FORMAT))

            infds, outfds, errfds = select.select([s], [s], [], 5)
            if len(infds) != 0:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                respuesta = str(data.decode(FORMAT))
                if len(data) != 0:
                    if respuesta == ' RPRT 0':
                        print("Envío exitoso")
                    
                    print('Received from the server :', str(data.decode(FORMAT)))
            if len(outfds) != 0:
                print("Esperando...\n")
```

La salida en pantalla es:
Esperando...

Received from the server : RPRT 0
¿Dónde esta mi fallo?

Comment: Mueve el `print` antes del `if` y mira que es lo que llega del servidor. Podria traer un `\n` al final del string.

Comment: Gracias lo pruebo